# IsoSurface Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, teechart

I have a large amount of data that I'm adding to a Surface chart in Android.  The graph is displayed correctly.  However, when I try to switch the chart type to IsoSurface, the application crashes.  I'm not sure why it crashes since it seems to be in the library itself.  I've included the output from LogCat of the crash

```
E/AndroidRuntime(3719): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(3719): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.drawing.Graphics3D.calc3DPos(Graphics3D.java:1110)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.styles.IsoSurface.loopLevels(IsoSurface.java:445)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.styles.IsoSurface.drawCell(IsoSurface.java:385)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.styles.Surface.drawAllCells(Surface.java:405)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.styles.Surface.draw(Surface.java:308)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.styles.IsoSurface.draw(IsoSurface.java:113)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.styles.Series.drawSeries(Series.java:2357)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.Chart.drawAllSeries(Chart.java:790)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.Chart.drawAxesSeries(Chart.java:752)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.Chart.internalDraw(Chart.java:732)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.Chart.paint(Chart.java:2080)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.Chart.paint(Chart.java:2096)
E/AndroidRuntime(3719):     at com.steema.teechart.TChart.onDraw(TChart.java:317)
```

Answer (score 1):

I can do this without errors:

```
Surface surf1 = new Surface(tChart1.getChart());
surf1.fillSampleValues();

try {
    Surface.changeType(surf1, IsoSurface.class);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please, post some code so we can reproduce the problem here.